# Ionic 3 - Android - Get of phone is using automatic date

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic-framework, time

It might sound stupid but I need to determinate whether the user's phone's set with Automatic Date & Time or not.

I'm showing some bars' status (opened/closed) depending on the user's current time. If the user's phone is not set on Automatic Date & Time, it will fail.

Is there a way to get this information with ionic?

Comment: "If the user's phone is not set on Automatic Date & Time, it will fail." why? What if my manually specified date and time is valid?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm not sure, but I guess it's something related to the timezone that's not correct if it's not set on "Automatic Date & Time". It's true that I need to debug it more, but I tried with 4 phones, 3 of them had date & time set automatically and one did not. That one was the one failing. The date and time were the same though. The timezone was not.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your app or a dependency. Does your application need the timezone? What is the error you receive?